# Access controller from button in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

In my  Yii 2 application, I'm trying to make download button.

Here's my download controller:

```
public function actionDownload()
{
    $path = 'templates/file';
    if(file_exists($path)){
        Yii::$app->response->sendFile($path);
    }
}
```

My button:

```
 <?= Html::a('Download Form', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
```

Is there a way to access the `function actionDownload()` from my button?

Comment: It should be `return Yii::$app->response->sendFile($path);` ...

Comment: @soju and how to access the controller ?

Comment: Look at *chinmay* answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<?= Html::a('Download Form', ['yourControllerName/download'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
```

Comment: Page not found. i can't access

Comment: Updated. Try with just download then.

Comment: still can't access. or could you provide a tutorial with example to access the Controller ?

Comment: Its working for me. You can check the official documentation here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#a%28%29-detail

Comment: can you give me a simple example ?